# Select without using $unwind (Mongoose aggregation)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am using Mongoose's aggregation (MongoDB v3.2). There are two items `factory1` and `factory2` in database. Each factory has a field `products` which is a array.

I want to select all factories which has product `code1=='aa'` & `code2=='BB'`

```
// factory1.products
[{
  code1: 'aa',
  code2: 'AA'
}, {
  code1: 'bb',
  code2: 'BB'
}]

// factory2.products
[{
  code1: 'aa'
  code2: 'BB'
}]
```

This is how I do now:

```
Factory
  .aggregate([
    { $unwind: '$products' },  // Ensure get factory2 only when use $match. Without $unwind, will get both factory1 and factory2
    { $match: {
      'products.code1': 'aa',
      'products.code2': 'BB'
    }}
  ]);
```

Is there a way to select without using `$unwind`? Because later I want to get the complete items again. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `$match` to use [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) to require that both terms be satisfied by the same `products` element:

```
Factory.aggregate([
  { $match: { products: { $elemMatch: {
    code1: 'aa',
    code2: 'BB'
  }}}}
]);
```

Comment: wow, thanks, works perfect! I just know $elemMatch can also be used in aggregation, not only in query!